# JQUERY UI - I can't get my items on autocomplete select event using a for loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a source that contains this :

```
"{Description1:"mydFirstDescription",Description2:"mySecondDescription",Description3:"myThirdescription"}"
```

I just want to loopt thro my 3 descriptions in my autocomplete select :

I already know how many descriptions I got ( I have it in a variable that I can access in my select ) so now the problem is in looping thro them and showing their content)

```
$(this).autocomplete({
    source: mysrouce,
    select: function (event, ui) 
      {
            numberOfDescriptions = ui.item.NbrDescriptions;
            for ( var k = 1 ; k <= NSNbrLignes ; k++ )
            {
                stringgg = ui.item.Description[k];
                alert(stringgg);

            }           

      }
```

Ps: the example I have here shows the following error :

```
ui.item.Description is undefined
```

Is there any way I can make this work ?

EDIT:

I create my source using php and this is the original content of my source:

```
string(467) "{label:"produit hiapps (Produit)",PrixVente:250,PrixRevient:100,UniteMesure:0,TVA:0},{label:"test service (Service)",PrixVente:16246,NbrLignes:3,unite1:"heures",Description1:"produit hiapps",Quantite1:1,PrixRevientLigService1:100,PrixVenteLigService1:250,unite2:"m2",Description2:"test",Quantite2:4,PrixRevientLigService2:555,PrixVenteLigService2:666,unite3:"h",Description3:"ezeffs",Quantite3:2,PrixRevientLigService3:444,PrixVenteLigService3:6666,PrixRevient:2408}"
```

Comment: If you need any explanations or need more informations about the question , just let me know

Comment: Can you show the line in your code where you create that source, because the quotes in there don't look right. Is it a `String`? In that case you're missing several `+` signs. Is it an object? Then the quotes are all wrong and should only be around the keys.

Comment: I forgot to delete the quotes in my example , i don't have them in my code, i will update the question

Comment: I see you edited some quotes, but those were not the quotes I was talking about ;) I meant the line `"{Description1:"mydFirstDescription",Description2:"mySecondDescription",Description3:"myThirdescription"}" `

Comment: I edited my question , I create that source and format it using php to match the requirements of the autocomplete source , and when I "alert'  ui.item.description1 it shows indeed its content , same thing for ui.item.description2 and 3 ,   my only problem is that I can't loop thro them and show them at each loop

Comment: Did you try `stringgg = ui.item.Description+k;`?

Comment: I tried it, it  returns  NaN

Comment: `ui.item.Description[k]` would indicate that there is an array `ui.item.Description`, but there isn't, hence the `undefined`. I think you can reference it using `ui.item['Description'+k]`.

Comment: It worked , can you make it an answer so I can accept it please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ui.item.Description[k]` would indicate that there is an array `ui.item.Description`, but there isn't, hence the `undefined`.

To get an object value by key name you can do `object['keyName']`, so in your case that would be `ui.item['Description'+k]`.

Comment: I spent almost 10 days now looking for a solution to this,  I appreciate your quick answer